# $\operatorname{Tor}_1^\mathbb{Z}(U,U)=0$. Is $U$ torsion-free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, torsion-groups

Let $U$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-module with $\operatorname{Tor}_1^\mathbb{Z}(U,U)=0$. Does this imply that $U$ is torsion-free?

I know that if $\operatorname{Tor}_1^\mathbb{Z}(U,M)=0$ for every $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M$, then $U$ is called flat (by definition), but this is stronger than $\operatorname{Tor}_1^\mathbb{Z}(U,U)=0$. On the other hand, flat implies torsion-free. However, I have no idea how to attack the question.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functor $\operatorname{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}_1$ is left exact in each variable (by the long exact sequence for Tor and the fact that $\operatorname{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}_2=0$).  So if $\operatorname{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}_1(U,U)=0$, then $\operatorname{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}_1(A,B)=0$ for any subgroups $A,B\subseteq U$.  Now if $U$ is not torsion-free, let $x\in U$ be a nonzero torsion element and let $A$ and $B$ to both be the cyclic subgroup generated by $x$.  Then $\operatorname{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}_1(A,B)\neq 0$ (since $\operatorname{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}_1(\mathbb{Z}/(n),\mathbb{Z}/(n))\cong\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ for all $n>0$), which is a contradiction.  Thus if $\operatorname{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}_1(U,U)=0$, then $U$ is torsion-free.

More generally, if $M$ and $N$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, then $\operatorname{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}_1(M,N)\neq 0$ iff there is a prime $p$ such that both $M$ and $N$ have elements of order $p$.  See [When is $\operatorname{Tor}_1 ^\mathbb{Z} (M,N) \neq 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2334066/when-is-operatornametor-1-mathbbz-m-n-neq-0) for the details.

Comment: Why U has a torsion element?

Comment: @Sky: I never said it did.  I just said _if_ it has a torsion element, you get a contradiction (so actually it doesn't).

Comment: sorry,this is a good observation.

Comment: I think is there a example such that there exists a module M(not flat) satisfying $Tor_1(M,M)=0$?

Comment: I suspect that is possible, but don't know an example off the top of my head.